# How to fix DVTToolchain: Failed to load toolchain using Xcode command line tools?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcrun

Anytime I run any command with `xcrun` or `xcodebuild` in the terminal it always outputs:

> VTToolchain: Failed to load toolchain: : Error Domain=DVTToolchainErrorDomain Code=4 "alleged toolchain directory doesn't contain ToolchainInfo.plist or Info.plist" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain, NSLocalizedDescription=alleged toolchain directory doesn't contain ToolchainInfo.plist or Info.plist}

I have opened the /Toolchains/switft-latest.xctoolchain and it contains Toolchain.Info.plist, so I am confused on how to fix this error. I have tried reinstalling Xcode and reinstalling Xcode command tools

These are my SDK paths:

```
xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcrun --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the link to the latest toolchain in `Library/Developer/Toolchains`.

```
$ cd /Library/Developer/Toolchains/
$ ls -l
$ -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  admin  1268976 Sep  3 04:43 swift-latest.xctoolchain
$ rm swift-latest.xctoolchain
```

I ran `xcodebuild` right after and I had no error. The issue was from previously downloading a new toolchain and Xcode didn't remove it correctly when I uninstalled it. I had help from this [github issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1352#issuecomment-227345350).